# Store first array and second array in another variable from a string variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <head>
            <title>Date</title>
            <script>

            function myFunction(){
                //Example I passed in 31-02-2013
                var timeDate = document.getElementById('date').text;

                //Get the first array and second array
                var date = { timeDate[0] , timeDate[1] };
                if( date < 1 || date > 30 )
                    alert( "Invalid date" );

            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Date : <input type="text" id="date" ></p>
        <input type="button" value=" Check it " onclick="myFunction()">
    </body>
```

I'm just use c++ concept to store the first array and second array of my string variables.
I didn't know how to store the array in HTML.
can someone teach me and correct me please?

Comment: Not very clear what you are asked here, in you need to stored data in HTML, take a look at HiddenFields

Comment: Why are you guessing at syntax? How about doing some research and [learning the basics of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS mentioned on one of the comments you need to brush up on some JavaScript basics.

First up you need  to access the `value` of an input element:

```
var timeDate = document.getElementById('date').value;
```

This will be interpreted as a string. You cannot access the characters in an array fashion. Instead you could use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the characters that you need.

Once you have the charters that you want they could still be treated as a string so your `date < 1` evaluation may produce some unexpected results. You would want to make sure you  are dealing with a numeric value. Something like [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

You could also use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break the date string into an array if you know the specific input format and separator used. Just be aware this will be an array of strings so heed the warning above.

Demonstration of the basics: http://jsfiddle.net/sdtPt/1/

Comment: okay i get it after demo the script to me. so can i ask if i wan to get the month substring , isn't 

var MONTH = timeDate.substring( 3,5 );
console.log( MONTH );

var monthArray = timeDate.split("-");
console.log(monthArray[3]);

var month = parseInt( monthArray[3],10 );
console.log( month );

Comment: @ChirsLim use substring OR split. I'd use split. Split with your date values with give you an array of 3 elements. AS an exercise, iterate through the array to see what is what. Also I'm using `console.log` to illustrate the values. It serves no functional purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of checking if the entered number is one between 1 and 30

```
(function (doc) {
    var date_form = doc.getElementById('date_form'),
        date_input = doc.getElementById('date_input'),

        warnInvalid = function (e) {
            //if invalid alert and prevent form submission
            alert('invalid date');
            e.preventDefault();
        },

        verifyDate = function (e) {
            var date = date_input.value;

            //pre cheking if empty or has letters
            if (date == '' || /\D/.test(date)
                || +date < 1 || date > 30) {
                warnInvalid(e);
            }
        };

    date_form.addEventListener('submit', verifyDate, false);
})(document);
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/rnBRb/